# Find modal matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

I was solving a Question from Higher Engineering Mathematics by BS Grewal of finding the modal matrix.
The Matrix A is given as
$$
A= \begin{bmatrix}1&2&3\\0&3&1\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}
$$
I found eigen values as $\begin{bmatrix}1&1&3\end{bmatrix}$.
And Corresponding Eigen Vectors are
$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\end{bmatrix}$,$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\end{bmatrix}$,$\begin{bmatrix}1&1&0\end{bmatrix}$.
As I have studied modal Matrix constitutes of eigen vectors but given answer is
$$
P= \begin{bmatrix}0&1&1\\-3&0&1\\2&0&0\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: Eigenvectors are not unique.

Comment: So how can I calculate modal matrix.

Comment: @AbhishekSingh The matrix is not diagonalizable, so there is no "modal matrix" in the sense of diagonalization.  Instead, you need a [generalized modal matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_matrix#Generalized_modal_matrix).

Comment: @AbhishekSingh Notably, a modal matrix must be invertible and therefore must have linearly independent columns, but the eigenvectors that you have found are not linearly independent (since the vector $(1,0,0)$ is repeated).

Comment: You can double check it yourself $A=PDP^{-1}$ but this fails in your case due to the reason mentioned by @BenGrossmann. You need the generalized vectors.